# JDBC queries slow... Until Wireshark is ran once

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, wireshark, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having a very strange problem. We're running a Java application, using Hibernate on top of JDBC, on a Windows Server 2012, on a VM.

When we try to read a lot of data from an Oracle 12c database, it's systematically super slow.

But once we run Wireshark once... It's instantly 100x faster! And it stays like this until we reboot the machine, even if we close Wireshark afterwards.

Any explanations? It really sounds like issue with Windows network cards drivers..

Edit 1 : We ruled out Hibernate : the problem happens as well with only JDBC
Edit 2 : We ruled out WinPcap, Wireshark without it still fixes the problem.

Comment: How many times did you try to read the data in Oracle before running Wireshark?

Comment: I had the same issue and I ended up deleting WinPcap and Wireshark.

Comment: Is the NPF service set to start automatically on boot? If so, then perhaps try setting it to Manual and then `NET START NPF` when you want to use Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but using a .Net application accessing a Oracle 12c database, and uninstalling WinPcap/Wireshark didn't solved the slowness problem.

As the environment in question runs under vmware, we have looked into issues related to the vmxnet3 driver (under Windows 2012 R2) and found, as a contouring solution, how to disable Receive Side Coalescing (RSC) feature on it. Without reboot, the problem is gone.

In Powershell:

Disable-NetAdapterRsc *

Source: [After upgrading a virtual machine to hardware version 11, network dependent workloads experience performance degradation (2129176)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2129176)